# Kubernetes Guestbook Example Not Loading Page

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

New question:

I've followed the guestbook tutorial here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/guestbook/README.md

And the output of my commands match their outputs exactly. When I try to access the guestbook web server, the page does not load.

Specifically, I have the frontend on port 80, I have enabled http/s connections on the console for all instances, I have run the command:

`gcloud compute firewall-rules create --allow=tcp:<PortNumberHere> --target-tags=TagNameHere TagNameHere-<PortNumberHere>`

and also

`cluster/kubectl.sh get services guestbook -o template --template='{{(index .status.loadBalancer.ingress 0).ip}}'`

But when I run curl -v http://:, the connection simply times out.

What am I missing?

---

### Old Question - Ignore:

Edit: Specifically, I have 3 separate docker images. How can I tell kubernetes to run these three images?

---

I have 3 docker images, each of which use each other to perform their tasks. One is influxdb, the other is a web app, and the third is an engine that does data processing.

I have managed to get them working locally on my machine with docker-compose, and now I want to deploy them on googles compute engine so that I can access it over the web. I also want to be able to scale the software. I am completely, 100% new to cloud computing, and have never used gce before.

I have looked at Kubernetes, and followed the docs, but I cannot get it to work on a gce instance. What am I missing/not understanding? I have searched and read all the docs I could find, but I still don't feel any closer to getting it than before.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/gce.md

Comment: What is the actual curl command you're running? Have you tried running curl on the machine itself against localhost?

Comment: And, to be clear, you actually wrote `80` above and not `<PortNumberHere>`?

Comment: Yes I put 80 and not <PortNumberHere>

Comment: Can you try without the target name and target tag? I suspect that may be what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To get best results on SO you need to ask specific questions.

But, to answer a general question with a general answer, Google's Cloud Platform Kubernetes wrapper is Container Engine. I suggest you run through the Container Engine tutorials, paying careful attention to the configuration files, before you attempt to implement your own solution.

See the guestbook to get started: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/guestbook

Comment: I have updated my post with a specific question/error I'm getting, I'm copying a short version here:

I've followed the guestbook tutorial here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/guestbook/README.md

and cannot connect to the guestbook webpage.

Answer (score 0):

To echo what rdc said, you should definitely go through the tutorial, which will help you understand the system better. But the short answer to your question is that you want to create a ReplicationController and specify the containers' information in the pod template.

Comment: I have updated my post with a specific question/error I'm getting, I'm copying a short version here:

I've followed the guestbook tutorial here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/guestbook/README.md

and cannot connect to the guestbook webpage.